# Is there a way to add sections to QListView?

Tags: qt, qlistview

I'm using Qt5.2 anc C++ to implement an application and need to display a list with sections similar to the example image below:

[image: mock-up]
<sub>(source: [ngo-hung.com](http://www.ngo-hung.com/files/images/contact_list_view_1.png))</sub>

Please note I'm not implementing a mobile app and I don't need the alphabet index on the right. Any suggestions how I can achieve this other than implementing a QTreeView?
Thanks.

Comment: Pretty easy to do in Qml.  For a QListView you might try just using a different delegate for the section headers.

Comment: `QToolBox` looks similar but not very convenient. I would write a proxy model that adds rows for letters and provides appropriate styling for them in `data()` implementation.

Comment: I'm at a similar hurdle. @PavelStrakhov, would it be possible to share an example of your suggestion? I'm familiar with the sort/filter model where it *removes* rows, but can't wrap my head around how to add them.

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` in QML has built-in support for sections. In the following example, I have a ListModel where the section is defined via a "sec" role. The `ListView` defines a section delegate as well as a contact delegate:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    title: "ListView sections demo"
    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: contacts
        header: ListViewHeaderDelegate { }
        delegate: ListViewDelegate { }
        section.property: "sec"
        section.delegate: ListViewSectionDelegate { }
    }
    ListModel {
        id: contacts
        ListElement { sec: "B"; fn: "Branda"; sn: "Respass" }
        ListElement { sec: "C"; fn: "Chana"; sn: "Hollin" }
        ListElement { sec: "D"; fn: "Delisa"; sn: "Deak" }
        ListElement { sec: "D"; fn: "Demetrius"; sn: "Zona" }
        ListElement { sec: "D"; fn: "Dwain"; sn: "Mark" }
    }
}

// ListViewHeaderDelegate.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Frame {
    width: ListView.view.width
    background: Rectangle { color: "red" }
    RowLayout {
        width: parent.width
        AppIconButton { icon.source: "address-book-32.svg" }
        AppHeadingText { text: qsTr("All Contacts") }
    }
}

// ListViewDelegate.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Frame {
    width: ListView.view.width
    RowLayout {
        width: parent.width
        AppIconButton {
            icon.source: "user-32.svg"
            icon.color: "green"
        }
        ColumnLayout {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            AppText { text: fn }
            AppText { text: qsTr("Full name: %1 %2").arg(fn).arg(sn) }
        }
    }
}

// ListViewSectionDelegate.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Frame {
    width: ListView.view.width
    background: Rectangle { color: "lightsteelblue" }
    RowLayout {
        AppHeadingText { text: section }
    }
}

// AppIconButton.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Item {
    id: iconButton
    property alias icon: button.icon
    Layout.preferredWidth: icon.width
    Layout.preferredHeight: icon.height
    Button {
        id: button
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        background: Item {}
        icon.width: 32
        icon.height: 32
        icon.color: "white"
    }
}

// AppText.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Text {
    Layout.fillWidth: true
}

// AppHeadingText.qml
AppText {
    color: "white"
}

// address-book-32.svg : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Esri/calcite-ui-icons/master/icons/address-book-32.svg
// user-32.svg : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Esri/calcite-ui-icons/master/icons/user-32.svg
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)